# IOS: Pass Array to another View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i recently started ios development and am kind of stuck here. I created an tabbed application. Inside the FirstViewController i hold a list of objects, containing coordinates. On the second tab I have a MapView.

I want to show a pin on the map for every coordinate in the list in ViewController 1 but I don't know how

1. I can access the Array in the other viewController
2. I can get informed when this list grows so the additional pins can be created

Comment: You should think about "modeling" your point data into some sort of structure that is accessible to both view controllers that need to know about it. This is a very common question.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about MVC or MVVM. In this design patterns you should use model which store Coordinates. And Controller or ViewModel must have link to this model.

ViewControllerA -> owns CoordinateModel
ViewControllerB -> owns the same CoordinateModel

Also, Coordinate model should inform both controllers about changes.

Answer (score 0):

If the map view controller needs to know about what's happening in the first controller, but not the other way around, I would suggest using delegation. Make the map view controller the delegate of the first controller, and have that first controller send a message to its delegate any time its array of objects changes.